# DenyHosts and no-ip.com

Tags: ssh, dynamic-dns, denyhosts

I recently installed `DenyHosts` and after a few remote logins I noticed that `sshd: 8.23.224.110` had been added to the `host.deny` file after `/var/log/auth.log` showed a few `sshd: Did not receive identification string from 8.23.224.110`. This appears to be `no-ip.com`.

I use `ddclient` to dynamically update my ip-address to point to my hostname at `no-ip.com`; something like `myhostname@no-ip.org` so that instead of having to `ssh` to a dynamic ip I can always just connect to the above host.

I don't understand why `8.23.224.110` would be trying to connect to my ssh service however, can anyone shed some light on this? Is it some kind of by product of me `ssh`'ing to the no-ip hosted hostname? Is it likely to be problematic now `DenyHosts` has banned it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending log captures to their abuse report?  They may have something that has been compromised, or mis-behaving on their network.  A long shot, but there are times when it does work.

```
Comment:        For abuse complaints please open a trouble ticket
Comment:        at http://www.no-ip.com/ticket or email abuse@no-ip.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why they would be, either. Possibly they're doing some sort of automated security check. Best to ask them. I'd guess that blocking it won't lead to any problems.

It doesn't have anything to do with you running `ssh your-host.no-ip.org`. That connection will show as coming from whichever machine you ssh from.

Comment: Yeah, I see the connection from remote host too in the logs. Curious as no what `no-ip` are doing then.